# NHibernate SaveOrUpdate merges child collections

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class `Journal`, which has an `IList` of `JournalLine` objects.

I created a `Journal` and accidentally ran it through the same line generation method twice. The start of this method calls `_journalLines.Clear()` and the end does `_session.SaveOrUpdate(journal)`. So I have this sequence:

1. Generate `Journal` with no lines, call `SaveOrUpdate`. That's fine.
2. Generate three `JournalLines` with IDs 1,2,3, add to `Journal._journalLines` and  call `SaveOrUpdate`
3. Call `Journal._journalLines.Clear()`. A breakpoint after this shows the lines list to be empty.
4. Generate three `JournalLines` with IDs 4,5,6, add to `Journal._journalLines` and  call `SaveOrUpdate`. A breakpoint here shows `_journalLines` to have three things in it.
5. I'm left with a `Journal` that has 6 lines.

This all takes place in one transaction and nothing is persisted in the database until it's finished.

Why is this merging the two collections? It seems to me that it should get to the last `SaveOrUpdate` where the breakpoint shows it's got three lines, and persist it as having three lines. Are the other three hanging around in memory somewhere because there hasn't been a flush yet?

Edit: Mapping

```
public JournalMap()
{
    // Other stuff
    HasMany(x => x.JournalLines)
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}

public JournalLineMap()
{
    // Other stuff
    References(x => x.Journal);
}
```

`Journal` has these:

```
private readonly IList<JournalLine> _journalLines = new List<JournalLine>();
public virtual IEnumerable<JournalLine> JournalLines 
                                       { get { return _journalLines; } }
```

The actual code that generates the lines is way too complicated to add here, but it calls `_journalLines.Add(journalLine);` after generating them, and then calls this, T being a `Journal`

```
 public T Add(T entity)
 {
     _session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
     return entity;
 }
```

Before ultimately calling `_session.Flush()` and `_session.Transaction.Commit();` if the flush doesn't error.

Comment: Is there a real reason as to why you would call SaveOrUpdate multiple times within a transaction?

Comment: #1 is part of a general method to create the thing that holds the journal, and #4 is a method that can be called independently, the other call (#2) was a mistake.

Comment: I guess #1 isn't strictly relevant for this, I'm more trying to figure out why #2 and #4 merge instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be related to the style of *Journal* mapping. Mostly the cascade setting used for your collection. If you are having cascade setting like **save-update** or **all**, e.g.

```
<bag name="JournalLines" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="save-update"
 ...
```

Then what is happening *(using similar step numbers)*:

1. ...
2. At this point, the collection contains Items 1,2,3 ... `SaveOrUpdate(jurnal)` will do the cascade. It also does the cascading, i.e. session is aware about these 3 items to be persisted
3. `Clear()` will clear the `IList<>` but there is no cascade trigger to remove these items from a session. At this moment, our first 3 JournalLines are really **orphans**. No one cares about them
4. ...
5. `Flush()` triggered by transaction will isnsert all the JournalLines into DB

Solution: change the mapping to

```
cascade="all-delete-orphan"
```

*NOTE: from definiton you've provided above, I guess that this is the scenario (I just explained)
Other issue you could be, if you call `session.SaveOrUpdate(eachJournalLine)`. In that case `Clear()` is not enough, you also have to iterate all removed items and set their relation to line.Journal = null*

Comment: The collection is already mapped as AllDeleteOrphan. What's weirder is that if, before calling `Clear()` on the collection, I loop through them and kill their reference to `Journal` manually, they still get committed, three with a ref to the `Journal` and three without. Surely these are orphans, and should be deleted.

Comment: OK, then show your mapping and code, please. Because I was able to reproduce your issues only with settings and calls I just described. Having more details, we can find what is wrong.

Comment: Have added more above.

Comment: I see the code I'd expected, nothing surprising. (Obviously you used adjusted snippets, describing the principle). Maybe suspected at the moment is some *hidden* call... Sorry, do not have better answer...